# Ncurse implements window stretching and text does not wrap

Tags: ncurses, htop

How to use NCurse to achieve window stretching, text does not wrap. Like the interface of HTOP, the window is stretched, and the process is not forced to show a line break, but hidden

Comment: The application has to repaint the window (ncurses won't guess which of the `waddstr` calls were meant to wrap in a resized window).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.